# I couldn't find a topic or hint for creating subtasks or nested tasks in Outlook Task

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Is it possible to add a sub-task to Outlook, or do we need an additional addin to do so?

I tried to look into it, but I couldn't find any information about it.

Answer (score 0):

Web add-ins don't provide anything for creating new items in Outlook. You may consider using EWS from a web add-in, see [Call web services from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services) for information. Also you may consider using the Graph API, see [Build Office Add-ins with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/office-addin). This is a preferred and recommend way of doing that.

Comment: I'd like to add that we do allow CreateItem EWS call via makeEwsRequestAsync JS API, but the recommended way to do this kind of scenario is indeed via the Graph API.

Comment: I've added a pointer about the recommended way.